# angularjs tutorial code debug

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

im learning angularjs thru an Apress book and I've come across some code that doesnt work, ive tried to debug but my console isnt giving me any errors or anything. Maybe some experts can guide me thru whats wrong, thanks.

customFilters.js file

```
// Creating a custom filter
// arguments for the filter method is unique and a factory function that returns a filter function that does the actaul work
angular.module('customFilters',[]).filter('unique', function() {
    return function(data, propertyname) {
        if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyname)) {
            var results = [];
            var keys = {};
            for (var i = 0; i  < data.length; i++) {
                var val = data[i][propertyname];
                if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
                    keys[val] = true;
                    results.push(val);
                }
            }
            return results;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    } 
});
```

sportsStore.js file

```
//declaring a dependency called customFilters that contains a unqiue filter
angular.module('sportsStore',['customFilters']);

// calling the angular.module method passing in sportsStore located in app.html
angular.module('sportsStore').controller('sportsStoreCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        products: [
            {name: "Product 1", description:"A product", category:"Category #1", price: 100},
            {name: "Product 2", description:"A product", category:"Category #1", price: 110},
            {name: "Product 3", description:"A product", category:"Category #2", price: 210},
            {name: "Product 4", description:"A product", category:"Category #3", price: 202}
        ]
    };
});
```

my productListControllers.js file

```
angular.module('sportsStore').controller('productListCtrl', function($scope,$filter){
   var selectedCategory = null;
   $scope.selectedCategory = function(newCategory) {
        selectedCategory = newCategory;
   };
   $scope.categoryFilterFn = function(product) {
        return selectedCategory == null || product.category == selectedCategory;
   };
});
```

app.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- We are defining the sportStore module here in the html tag-->
<html ng-app="sportsStore">
    <head>
        <title>Sports Store</title>
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <!-- Applying ng-controller to the body tagg -->
    <body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sports Store</a>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default row" ng-controller="productListCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="selectCategory()">Home</a>
        <!-- generating the navigation elements here -->
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg" ng-repeat="item in data.products |orderBy:'category'| unique:'category'" ng-click="selectCategory(item)">{{item}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
        <!-- ng-repeat generates elements for each object in an array -->
        <!-- we also create a local variable called item --> 
        <div class="well" ng-repeat="item in data.products | filter:categoryFilterFn">
            <h3>
            <strong>{{item.name}}</strong>
            <span class="pull-right label label-primary">{{item.price | currency}}</span>
            </h3>
            <span class="lead">{{item.description}}</span>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>




        <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
    <script src="filters/customFilters.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/productListControllers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not seeing a problem with this code.  Do you have an angular.js file in the same directory as the app.html file?  try switching the <script src="angular.js"></script> to <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>  That way we are sure that you have a good angular file.

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js << that is what goes into the src.  SO appears to be truncating the one above.

Comment: @DavidEdwards hey david, thanks for the input, but unfortunately that didn't work, it still doesn't filter whenever i click on different categories.

Comment: Oh ok.  I think I see.  Just to be sure, selectCategory(item) is not running when you click on item.  Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your html file.  The function is selectedCategory not selectCategory.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, the template says `selectCategory` and the controller says `selectedCategory`

Comment: i have that included in my sportsStore.js file

Comment: Can you post the content of sportsStore.js or make a plunker?

Comment: You put the `ng-app` on the wrong spot put it on the `body`. See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFK83WbP2pG3zg35hCue?p=preview)

Comment: ng-app can go on the html tag.  it just makes the whole file an angular app instead of just the body.

Comment: Is there a typo on the code? The template says `selectCategory` and the controller says `selectedCategory`. See [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/MFK83WbP2pG3zg35hCue?p=preview)

edit: 
My comment was 30s late, see DavidEdward's comment

Comment: LOL!!! WOW, my book has a typo as well. Thanks for everything and good eye!! I took 2 days too figure this out myself, thanks again!!!